# Tell me how to handle objects before sending axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React.

Raise the child object to the parent.
I want to delete the unnecessary value and send it.

```
const before = {
  address_check: true,
  loan_check: true,
  oneroom_disable: true,
  info: {
   age: 13,
   name: gogo,
   item: [1,2,3]
  },
 face: {
 life: [1,2,3]
 }
};
```

ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ

```
const after = {
  address_check: true,
  age: 13,
  name: gogo,
  item: [1,2,3]
};
```

How can I change the status from before to after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
// Original data
const before = {
  address_check: true,
  loan_check: true,
  oneroom_disable: true,
  info: {
   age: 13,
   name: gogo,
   item: [1,2,3]
  },
 face: {
 life: [1,2,3]
 }
};

// Destructure required fields
const {address_check, info: {age, name, item}} = before;

// Put them together for your new object
const after = {
  address_check, age, name, item
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create object from other object like below:-

```
const after = {
  address_check: before.address_check,
  age: before.info.age,
  name: before.info.name,
  item: before.info.item
}
```